# What is the symbol "=>" doing after my method in this C# code?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I recently asked a question here, and someone provided this answer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var client = new WebClient();
     Uri X = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

     client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) => //THIS, WHAT IS IT DOING?
     {
         if (args.Error == null && !args.Cancelled)
         {
             MessageBox.Show();
         }
     };

     client.DownloadStringAsync(X);
}
```

What is that => doing? It's the first time I'm seeing this.

Comment: Lambda operator. According to what I've read, it's pronounced "goes to" when speaking out loud (just as a side note).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx for more info....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically it says "I am giving you this `(s,b)`" and you are returning me `s*b` or something and if you are using lambda with expressions, but it can be something like this : I am giving you this `(s,b)` and do something with them in the statement block like :

```
{
  int k = a+b;
  k = Math.Blah(k);
  return k;
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

A `Lambda` expression is an unnamed method written in place of a delegate instance. The compiler immediately converts the lambda expression to either :

- A delegate instance
- An expression Tree

`delegate int Transformer(int i);`

```
class Test{
  static void Main(){
     Transformer square = x => x*x;
     Console.WriteLine(square(3));
  } 

}
```

We could rewrite it like this :

`delegate int Transformer(int i);`

```
class Test{
  static void Main(){
     Transformer square = Square;
     Console.WriteLine(square(3));
  } 
  static int Square (int x) {return x*x;}
}
```

A lambda expression has the following form :

`(parameters) => expression or statement-block`

In previous example there was a single parameter,`x`, and the expression is `x*x`

in our example, x corresponds to parameter i, and the expression `x*x` corresponds to the return type `int`, therefore being compatible with Transformer delegate;

`delegate int Transformer ( int i);`

A lambda expression's code can be a statement block instead of an expression. We can rewrite our example as follows :

```
x => {return x*x;}
```

An expression tree, of type `Expression<T>`, representing the code inside the lamda expression in a traversable object model. This allows the lambda expression to be intrepreted later at runtime (Please check the "Query Expression" for LINQ)

Answer (score 19):

That is the lambda operator.  You define an anonymous function which takes two arguments (s, args) (type specifiers omitted), and the body of said function is what appears after the => symbol.

It is conceptually the same as this:

```
...
client.DownloadStringCompleted += Foo;
}

void Foo(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Error == null && !args.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The => is the [Lambda Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). It's a handy little guy that can help make your code more readable and less cluttered.