# what the sign "=>" mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I've the following code and I can't fully understand what's happen there:

```
Authorize auth = new Authorize(
    this.google,
    (DesktopConsumer consumer, out string requestToken) =>
    GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(
        consumer,
        GoogleConsumer.Applications.Contacts | GoogleConsumer.Applications.Blogger,
        out requestToken));
```

Here's what I know:
"Authorize" - have only 1 constructor which accept 2 arguments: (DesktopConsumer, FetchUri).
"this.google" - is a "desktopConsumer" object.
"GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization" returns a "Uri" object.

I can't understand what's the meaning of the line:
`(DesktopConsumer consumer, out string requestToken) =>`
in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640684/what-is-the-symbol-doing-after-my-method-in-this-c-sharp-code

Comment: common sign for LINQ users...

Comment: This makes a good case for not using some of these obscure characters in your code if someone else might have to read it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# => operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781268/c-sharp-operator)

Comment: For those who say it's a duplicate, it's is. but for some reason "=>" is ignored in a search... (here or google's) and if one doesn't know it's a LINQ, how can he find it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case `=>` creates an anonymous method/delegate using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) with the arguments `DesktopConsumer consumer, out string requestToken`.

Answer (score 4):

The `=>` operator is sometimes called the "goes to" operator.  It's part of the lambda syntax in which an anonymous method is created.  To the left of the operator are the arguments to the method, to the right is the implementation.

See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block. The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x times x."

Answer (score 2):

No fo time this question asked this a sign for lambda expression `=>`

**What is Lambda expression ?**

```
Lambda expression is replacement of the anonymous method avilable in C#2.0 Lambda expression can do all thing which can be done by anonymous method. 


Lambda expression are sort and function consist of single line or block of statement.
```

read this : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/lamda-expressions.html

read more about it on msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It means in english 'translates to'.  It forms part of a lambda expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Its an lambda function.  The () part is defining the parameters being passed to it, and the part after => is what is being evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the lambda operator means "using these parameters, execute the following code".

So it essntially defines an anonymous function to which you can pass a DesktopConsumer and a string (which can also be modified within the function and sent back).

Answer (score 2):

The "=>" is used in lamdba expressions.

```
(DesktopConsumer consumer, out string requestToken) =>         
    GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(
        consumer,
        GoogleConsumer.Applications.Contacts | GoogleConsumer.Applications.Blogger,
        out requestToken)
```

Is a very short form of a method declaration, where the method name is unknown (the method is anonymous). You could replace this code by:

```
private void Anonymous (DesktopConsumer consumer, out string requestToken)
{
    return GoogleConsumer.RequestAuthorization(
        consumer,
        GoogleConsumer.Applications.Contacts | GoogleConsumer.Applications.Blogger,
        out requestToken);
}
```

And then replace the call by:

```
Authorize auth = new Authorize(this.google, Anonymous);
```

Note that Anonymous is not called here (see the missing parentheses ()). Not the result of Anonymous is passed as parameter, but Anonymous itself is passed as delegate. Authorize will call Anonymous at some point and pass it actual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[Lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781282/273200) for some more details.